# IoT : Gateway to manager devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, open-source, iot

I want to start an IoT project with multiple machines (i.e., Raspberry Pis) in different locations (i.e., throughout a city or several cities).

Each machine should be able to send data to a back-end (ex., alive ping, sensor read-out updates, etc.) or receive orders from a back-end and send back response.

I don't want to start from scratch (can't use Amazon or Azure IoT service) - is there a framework that would do this (can register to the service and allow me to check which machines are up/down, send them messages, etc.)? I would prefer open-source possibilities, if possible.

Comment: The Bluemix IoT platform has gateways which can act as intermediaries for other devices that want to connect to the Watson IoT Platform.  Here are some links that provide more detail:

https://developer.ibm.com/iotfoundation/blog/2016/01/20/support-for-gateways-now-available-in-internet-of-things-foundation-beta/

https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connect-raspberry-pi-as-gateway-to-watson-iot-platform/

https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/raspberry-pi-as-managed-gateway-in-watson-iot-platform-part-1/

Comment: Whereabouts in the world is this to take place?

Answer (score 2):

For seeing what's going on with all those devices, and notification of problems, and automating any processes, then [DevicePilot](https://devicepilot.com) is worth a look. It's not an IoT platform though (there are plenty of those).

Answer (score -1):

Cumulocity offers a complete Software-as-a-service to do that.
Raspberry Pi integration is described here:
http://www.cumulocity.com/guides/devices/raspberry-pi/  (Java Agent)
or here:
http://www.cumulocity.com/guides/devices/janztec/ (C++ Agent)

The agents  are open source (under https://bitbucket.org/m2m/ ), the server-side platform is not open source (except examples). But you can get a free trial (see http://www.cumulocity.com/ ).

On

> It would work like that: upon start, raspberry would register to the service, once done, the service allow me to check which machines are up / down, send them messages etc.

This is supported out of the box without programming. Please see links above.

- Stefan (working for Cumulocity)